# Counting Posts by Category

Tags: posts, wp-query, count

I am trying to learn WP Query but finding it a little hard going. I have Posts created from a Forum Plugin (wps_forum_post) and I wish to display counts in descending order based on their selected category (wps_forum_post .meta.wps_fe_brand-retailer-service) and within that three more counts from a further selection (wps_forum_post .meta.wps_fe_overall-experience). I can not seem to be able to get my head around how to do this.

I want to display the results similar to this:

Brand B Posts (Total 32) - POSITIVE (10) INDIFFERENT (12) NEGATIVE (10)
Brand C Posts (Total 28) - POSITIVE (8) INDIFFERENT (10) NEGATIVE (10)
Brand A Posts (Total 26) - POSITIVE (10) INDIFFERENT (10) NEGATIVE (6)

Answer (score 0):

0
down vote
accepted

I think it would help you to read this => http://wordpress.org/support/topic//display-number-of-posts-per-category

```
function number_postpercat($idcat) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT count FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = $idcat";
    $num = $wpdb->get_col($query);
    echo $num[0];

}
```

Comment: It's not a very good idea to write SQL in this manner. Also it would be much nicer, if you used `get_var` instead of `get_col` since you gen only one value... And I don't think your function solves the problem. All you get is count of posts for given term, not the list of terms sorted by count of posts...

Comment: That's a very elegant solution and thank you. I just have to work out now how to ally this to the custom Forum Post Category which is not a Wordpress Category and to work out the overall Category descending order.

Comment: Krzysiek thank you also yes not a complete solution but at least I am beginning to see a way.